# How to get multiple first matches from regex?

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I'm using regular expressions to extract all class names from a CSS file. The regex works well if there is only one class, for example `.test {margin: 0}`, but if there is a set of classes, for example `.test.second.third {margin:0}`, I need only the first class als result: `.test`.

My current regex gives me `.test, .second, .third`. This is fine, but not what I need in this case. Where is the error in my regular expression?

I'm using it with JavaScript:

```
code = code.match(/(?:[\.]{1})([a-zA-Z_]+[\w-_]*)(?:[\s\.\,\{\>#\:]{0})/igm);
```

Or here as regex101 sheet: https://regex101.com/r/sgjrHt/1

Comment: Like `(?<!\S)\.\w+(?:-\w+)*` or `(?<!\S)\.\w+(?:-\w+)*(?=[^{}\n]*\{[^{}\n]*})` https://regex101.com/r/1NtywM/1

Comment: Hi :) I think this would not work with: .hello-world {}

Comment: Does there have to be a part with curly's `{}` present? If a positive lookbehind is supported `(?<!\S)\.\w+(?:-\w+)*(?=[^{}\n]*\{[^{}\n]*})` https://regex101.com/r/ypbAzg/1

Comment: Oh, your new edited regex allows "-" characters. But it does not allow colons. In modern frameworks there are classes like: .hello:world {} How could we match this?  Thanks by the way :)

Comment: You can add it to a character class https://regex101.com/r/cymXkt/1

Comment: Wow, we are close! Last problem: Multiple lines are not matching: https://regex101.com/r/cjbfqY/1

Comment: Yes then you can remove the newline from the negated character class https://regex101.com/r/MXwJcD/1

Comment: Amazing! Hehe, very very last step: https://regex101.com/r/RBhlEG/1 .test--test not matching. Adding "--" to the character class has no effect..

Comment: What about this: https://regex101.com/r/Rz50ad/1 ? I've added a "*" after the characters list. Is this fine?

Comment: You can extend the character class with the characters that you want to allow in between and also use a quantifier for them. Where are you using the pattern? https://regex101.com/r/MiriMV/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern:

- This part `(?:[\.]{1})` is the same as writing `\.`
- Using `\w` also matches `_` so you don't have to add them both to a character class like this `[\w-_]`
- Note that in that format you would have to escape the hyphen or put it at the start or the end of the character class

If a lookbehind assertion [is supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind):

```
(?<!\S)\.\w+(?:[:-]+\w+)*(?=[^{}]*\{[^{}]*})
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `\.\w+` Match `.` and 1+ word chars
- `(?:[:-]+\w+)*` Optionally repeat matching `:` or `-` and 1+ word chars
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert to the right

  - `[^{}]*` Match optional chars other than `{` and `}`
  - `\{[^{}]*}` Match `{...}`
- `)` Close the lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MiriMV/1)

Without a lookbehind you can use a capture group:

```
(?:\s|^)(\.\w+(?:[:-]+\w+)*)[^{}]*\{[^{}]*}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tgQnZ9/1)

Comment: Thanks so much! Additional question. When you check this: https://regex101.com/r/qpMo5F/1, you see that `.class1, class2 {}` works, but not when before the class2 no space exists: `.class1,class2 {}`. It works by removing `(?<!\S)`. Is this way even clean and can I go with?

Comment: Addition: It works by removing `(?<!\S)`, but then I loose the rule that I don't want to match `class1.class2` 

Comment: @asored In that case you can assert not a word character to the left https://regex101.com/r/UULukP/1

Comment: You are not from this world! So simple after reading your comments. Thanks a lot!